# Repetitive Battery Percentage Notifications (Razer, 20.04)

Tags: battery, notification

### System/software info

- Ubuntu 20.04
- Kernel version `5.4.0-29`
- Openrazer version `2.8.0~1~524`
- Polychromatic version `0.3.12`

Updated to `5.4.0-29` today, and with this update, my wireless mouse's battery percentage is now periodically displayed as a notification on the top of my screen. At first, I found this very useful, as I thought the notifications were only for low battery percentage, however, they are showing up seemingly every time that the percentage changes **[Edit: they also just happen on a random interval apparently, even when the percentage doesn't chane]**, see the screenshot below:

[image]

(Apologies for the image quality, couldn't find a great way to snap a picture of the notification dialog)

I have two questions branching from this.

1. What software is displaying this notification?
2. How can I change when it is displayed?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Credits to https://github.com/polychromatic/polychromatic/issues/147#issuecomment-380219281

The battery notification feature is part of the OpenRazer daemon itself -- Polychromatic has no control over it.

To disable it, there's an option inside `~/.config/openrazer/razer.conf` in your home directory:

```
# Mouse battery notifier
mouse_battery_notifier = True
```

To change when it sends a notification, edit `/usr/lib/python3/dist-packages/openrazer_daemon/misc/battery_notifier.py` as root and set the interval at line 16:

```
INTERVAL_FREQ = 60 * 10
```

(In seconds, so 10 minutes)

(Also note that editing this file will cause it to get overwritten when OpenRazer updates)